# Minecraft isn't launching?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My Minecraft isn't launching! I use the TeamExtreme 3.4 launcher, but even using the original launcher, I get the same thing! It says: `Unable to delete 1.7.10-native-4048111086702` and
the crash report says the following :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x05013e88, pid=416, tid=3624
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4dev32.dll+0x3e88]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x007adc00):  JavaThread "Client thread" [_thread_in_native, id=3624, stack(0x00740000,0x00790000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0c86d000

Registers:
EAX=0x00ffffff, EBX=0x000001e0, ECX=0x000001e0, EDX=0x0537007c
ESP=0x0078f87c, EBP=0x00ffffff, ESI=0x00000076, EDI=0x0c86d000
EIP=0x05013e88, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0078f87c)
0x0078f87c:   00000000 052513f0 00000356 000001e0
0x0078f88c:   00000d80 00000020 0c600000 00495768
0x0078f89c:   0501897e 0c86d000 00417570 00000000
0x0078f8ac:   065478d8 000000ff 00000000 00000000
0x0078f8bc:   00000356 000001e0 0537007c 00495400
0x0078f8cc:   00496068 00496068 04cf129e 065478d8
0x0078f8dc:   00ffffff 00000000 00000000 00000356
0x0078f8ec:   000001e0 00000000 00000000 04ceba19 

Instructions: (pc=0x05013e88)
0x05013e68:   8a b0 07 00 00 d3 e0 0b e8 85 f6 0f 8e 94 00 00
0x05013e78:   00 8d a4 24 00 00 00 00 85 db 7e 0a 8b cb 8b c5
0x05013e88:   f3 ab 8b 7c 24 24 03 7c 24 10 4e 89 7c 24 24 75
0x05013e98:   e7 eb 72 8b 44 24 34 8b 6c 24 48 8b 8d a8 07 00 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00ffffff is an unknown value
EBX=0x000001e0 is an unknown value
ECX=0x000001e0 is an unknown value
EDX=0x0537007c is an unknown value
ESP=0x0078f87c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x007adc00
EBP=0x00ffffff is an unknown value
ESI=0x00000076 is an unknown value
EDI=0x0c86d000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00740000,0x00790000],  sp=0x0078f87c,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ig4dev32.dll+0x3e88]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglClear(IJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear(I)V+15
j  bmg.f()V+54
j  bmg.b(II)V+181
j  bmg.a(II)V+37
j  bmg.<init>(IIZ)V+62
j  bbo.<init>(Lbao;)V+62
j  bao.ag()V+1236
j  bao.f()V+6
j  net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+1007
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x04560000 JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=1196, stack(0x09c90000,0x09ce0000)]
  0x045fe400 JavaThread "Thread-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3808, stack(0x046e0000,0x04730000)]
  0x03c0b400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2192, stack(0x047c0000,0x04810000)]
  0x04352800 JavaThread "Timer hack thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3048, stack(0x04670000,0x046c0000)]
  0x0435cc00 JavaThread "Snooper Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2796, stack(0x04830000,0x04880000)]
  0x0086f000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2104, stack(0x03820000,0x03870000)]
  0x00864800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=836, stack(0x039c0000,0x03a10000)]
  0x00863800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3708, stack(0x03950000,0x039a0000)]
  0x00860400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3396, stack(0x00ad0000,0x00b20000)]
  0x007f6c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3072, stack(0x03890000,0x038e0000)]
  0x007f1c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2360, stack(0x00690000,0x006e0000)]
=>0x007adc00 JavaThread "Client thread" [_thread_in_native, id=3624, stack(0x00740000,0x00790000)]

Other Threads:
  0x007f0800 VMThread [stack: 0x00930000,0x00980000] [id=196]
  0x00891000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x03ab0000,0x03b00000] [id=2828]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 11007K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K,  53% used [0x13c30000, 0x1461bcc0, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,  35% used [0x15110000, 0x151e41d8, 0x15360000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000, 0x15110000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 31152K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  65% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x2053c338, 0x2053c400, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 10046K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  81% used [0x33c30000, 0x345ffbb8, 0x345ffc00, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)

Card table byte_map: [0x00990000,0x00ac0000] byte_map_base: 0x008f1e80

Polling page: 0x00120000

Code Cache  [0x01790000, 0x01998000, 0x03790000)
 total_blobs=1348 nmethods=1048 adapters=236 free_code_cache=30703Kb largest_free_block=31439488

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 9.573 Thread 0x00864800 1054             java.util.ComparableTimSort::binarySort (223 bytes)
Event: 9.573 Thread 0x00864800 nmethod 1054 0x01993088 code [0x019931d0, 0x019935d8]
Event: 9.580 Thread 0x00864800 1055             bpx::a (63 bytes)
Event: 9.580 Thread 0x00864800 nmethod 1055 0x01993988 code [0x01993ad0, 0x01993c3c]
Event: 9.581 Thread 0x00864800 1056             bqd::a (5 bytes)
Event: 9.581 Thread 0x00864800 nmethod 1056 0x01993d88 code [0x01993e80, 0x01993f00]
Event: 9.581 Thread 0x00864800 1057             bqd::b (5 bytes)
Event: 9.581 Thread 0x00864800 nmethod 1057 0x01993f48 code [0x01994040, 0x019940c0]
Event: 9.594 Thread 0x00864800 1058             java.lang.String::trim (77 bytes)
Event: 9.595 Thread 0x00864800 nmethod 1058 0x01994248 code [0x01994350, 0x0199448c]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 8.419 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=20 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 17213K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K,  90% used [0x13c30000, 0x14cff628, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,   0% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000, 0x15110000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x15110000, 0x15110000, 0x15360000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 28459K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  59% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x2029ac18, 0x2029ae00, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9429K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  76% used [0x33c30000, 0x345656f0, 0x34565800, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
Event: 8.421 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=21 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 203K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K,   0% used [0x13c30000, 0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,   8% used [0x15110000, 0x15142c28, 0x15360000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000, 0x15110000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 28459K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  59% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x2029ac18, 0x2029ae00, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9429K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  76% used [0x33c30000, 0x345656f0, 0x34565800, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
}
Event: 8.505 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=21 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 19211K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K, 100% used [0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,   8% used [0x15110000, 0x15142c28, 0x15360000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000, 0x15110000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 28459K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  59% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x2029ac18, 0x2029ae00, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9433K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  76% used [0x33c30000, 0x34566488, 0x34566600, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
Event: 8.508 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=22 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 720K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K,   0% used [0x13c30000, 0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,  30% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14f741a0, 0x15110000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x15110000, 0x15110000, 0x15360000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 28459K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  59% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x2029ac18, 0x2029ae00, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9433K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  76% used [0x33c30000, 0x34566488, 0x34566600, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
}
Event: 8.898 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=22 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 19728K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K, 100% used [0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,  30% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14f741a0, 0x15110000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x15110000, 0x15110000, 0x15360000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 28459K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  59% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x2029ac18, 0x2029ae00, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9948K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  80% used [0x33c30000, 0x345e7358, 0x345e7400, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
Event: 8.909 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=23 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 2368K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K,   0% used [0x13c30000, 0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K, 100% used [0x15110000, 0x15360000, 0x15360000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000, 0x15110000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 28741K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  60% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x202e1760, 0x202e1800, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9948K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  80% used [0x33c30000, 0x345e7358, 0x345e7400, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
}
Event: 9.128 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=23 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 21376K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K, 100% used [0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K, 100% used [0x15110000, 0x15360000, 0x15360000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000, 0x15110000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 28741K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  60% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x202e1760, 0x202e1800, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9950K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  80% used [0x33c30000, 0x345e7aa8, 0x345e7c00, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
Event: 9.141 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=24 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 1251K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K,   0% used [0x13c30000, 0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,  52% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ff8e60, 0x15110000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x15110000, 0x15110000, 0x15360000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 30579K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  64% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x204acf70, 0x204ad000, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9950K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  80% used [0x33c30000, 0x345e7aa8, 0x345e7c00, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
}
Event: 9.509 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=24 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 20259K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K, 100% used [0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,  52% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ff8e60, 0x15110000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x15110000, 0x15110000, 0x15360000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 30579K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  64% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x204acf70, 0x204ad000, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9964K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  81% used [0x33c30000, 0x345eb198, 0x345eb200, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
Event: 9.513 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=25 (full 3):
 def new generation   total 21376K, used 848K [0x13c30000, 0x15360000, 0x1e6d0000)
  eden space 19008K,   0% used [0x13c30000, 0x13c30000, 0x14ec0000)
  from space 2368K,  35% used [0x15110000, 0x151e41d8, 0x15360000)
  to   space 2368K,   0% used [0x14ec0000, 0x14ec0000, 0x15110000)
 tenured generation   total 47432K, used 31152K [0x1e6d0000, 0x21522000, 0x33c30000)
   the space 47432K,  65% used [0x1e6d0000, 0x2053c338, 0x2053c400, 0x21522000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9964K [0x33c30000, 0x34830000, 0x37c30000)
   the space 12288K,  81% used [0x33c30000, 0x345eb198, 0x345eb200, 0x34830000)
    ro space 10240K,  41% used [0x37c30000, 0x38062050, 0x38062200, 0x38630000)
    rw space 12288K,  52% used [0x38630000, 0x38c76800, 0x38c76800, 0x39230000)
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 9.587 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x14581b18 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.588 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x14588be0 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.590 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x1458c820 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.590 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x1458fee8 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.591 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x14595190 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.591 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x14598be8 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.592 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x1459ed68 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.595 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x145c43e0 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.596 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x145c8970 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 9.596 Thread 0x007adc00 Threw 0x145cb570 at C:\re\jdk7u51\527\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1244

Events (10 events):
Event: 9.591 loading class 0x03c6f3f8
Event: 9.591 loading class 0x03c6f3f8 done
Event: 9.592 loading class 0x03c6f410
Event: 9.592 loading class 0x03c6f410 done
Event: 9.595 loading class 0x03c73960
Event: 9.595 loading class 0x03c73960 done
Event: 9.596 loading class 0x03c6f3b0
Event: 9.596 loading class 0x03c6f3b0 done
Event: 9.596 loading class 0x03c60790
Event: 9.596 loading class 0x03c60790 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00b60000 - 0x00b8f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x77790000 - 0x778cc000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x77610000 - 0x776e4000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75a30000 - 0x75a7b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x776f0000 - 0x77790000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x765c0000 - 0x7666c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x778d0000 - 0x778e9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x76510000 - 0x765b2000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x75be0000 - 0x75ca9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x75dd0000 - 0x75e1e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x75e20000 - 0x75e2a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x77920000 - 0x779bd000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x746f0000 - 0x7488e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x76290000 - 0x762e7000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x756e0000 - 0x7572c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6c360000 - 0x6c3ed000     C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.DLL
0x756c0000 - 0x756db000     C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x76940000 - 0x7758a000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x75f20000 - 0x7607c000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x75d40000 - 0x75dcf000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x74dc0000 - 0x74dd7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x757b0000 - 0x757bb000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x70250000 - 0x702a1000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x71370000 - 0x71382000     C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x778f0000 - 0x7790f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x75b10000 - 0x75bdc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x72190000 - 0x7224f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x6ae90000 - 0x6b210000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x71820000 - 0x71827000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x75eb0000 - 0x75ee5000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x77910000 - 0x77916000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x717b0000 - 0x717e2000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75e30000 - 0x75e35000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x736c0000 - 0x736cc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x73420000 - 0x73440000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x73400000 - 0x73413000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x72cc0000 - 0x72cca000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\management.dll
0x73360000 - 0x73374000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
0x751e0000 - 0x7521c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x751d0000 - 0x751d6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x74420000 - 0x7442f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
0x73e70000 - 0x73e80000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x73660000 - 0x73670000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x72fd0000 - 0x72fe2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x750a0000 - 0x750e4000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x73620000 - 0x73628000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x71340000 - 0x71367000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x71310000 - 0x71331000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x73c50000 - 0x73c6c000     C:\Windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x73c70000 - 0x73c77000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x73ba0000 - 0x73bd8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x71300000 - 0x71306000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x10000000 - 0x1004d000     C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-4048111086702\lwjgl.dll
0x6b370000 - 0x6b438000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x72130000 - 0x72152000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x6b280000 - 0x6b367000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x72cb0000 - 0x72cb6000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x767a0000 - 0x7693d000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75860000 - 0x75887000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75890000 - 0x758a2000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x73d70000 - 0x73d83000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x74c60000 - 0x74c69000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x75220000 - 0x75236000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x74fc0000 - 0x74ffb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x75730000 - 0x7573c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x6b440000 - 0x6b583000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\awt.dll
0x74360000 - 0x743a0000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x04af0000 - 0x04ee2000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4icd32.dll
0x05010000 - 0x052aa000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4dev32.dll
0x75cb0000 - 0x75d33000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6c8e0000 - 0x6c959000     C:\Windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x71e60000 - 0x71e98000     C:\Windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x70a40000 - 0x70a7a000     C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-4048111086702\avutil-ttv-51.dll
0x65980000 - 0x6599d000     C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-4048111086702\swresample-ttv-0.dll
0x6eb80000 - 0x6ec09000     C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-4048111086702\libmp3lame-ttv.dll
0x5e8d0000 - 0x5f850000     C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-4048111086702\libmfxsw32.dll
0x6ad80000 - 0x6ae83000     C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-4048111086702\twitchsdk.dll
0x76080000 - 0x7623d000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x75830000 - 0x75834000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-user32-l1-1-0.dll
0x758b0000 - 0x758b4000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-shlwapi-l1-1-0.dll
0x75a20000 - 0x75a24000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-version-l1-1-0.dll
0x75850000 - 0x75853000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-normaliz-l1-1-0.dll
0x75e40000 - 0x75e43000     C:\Windows\system32\normaliz.DLL
0x762f0000 - 0x76509000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x758c0000 - 0x758c5000     C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-downlevel-advapi32-l1-1-0.dll
0x07700000 - 0x07765000     C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-4048111086702\OpenAL32.dll
0x743a0000 - 0x743d9000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x74440000 - 0x74535000     C:\Windows\System32\PROPSYS.dll
0x6ad00000 - 0x6ad72000     C:\Windows\system32\dsound.dll
0x743e0000 - 0x74405000     C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll
0x732c0000 - 0x732f6000     C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x69c10000 - 0x69cfb000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.7.10\1.7.10-natives-4048111086702 
java_command: net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username m --version 1.7.10 --gameDir C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft --assetsDir C:\Users\Hamoudi\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets --assetIndex 1.7.10 --uuid a081287b21964f6da2f0ec10ea1fa4bc --accessToken 1337535510N --userProperties {} --userType legacy
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
USERNAME=Hamoudi
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 2087352k(766272k free), swap 4174704k(2135828k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.51-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_51-b13), built on Dec 18 2013 19:09:58 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Mon Jul 07 01:10:01 2014
elapsed time: 9 seconds
```

Why is this so? Could someone help me?

Comment: Would those voting to close as illegal/unreleased please explain why?  I'm not seeing anything in here to warrant that designation.

Comment: @Frank I think it is because of [this](http://imgur.com/WJxs7qN)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should go to `%appdata%/.minecraft`.
There you will find versions, from there you should go to 1.7.10
Then, all you have to do is find the folder and delete it.
If it's a deeper problem than that, Please tell me. I'll reply.

Comment: Probably a deeper issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

TeamExtreme's launcher is a cracked launcher and therefore is:

-Buggy
-TOTALLY not official
And therefore it is hard to provide feedback to your problem, as you are using a launcher not validated by Mojang and therefore the general community does not know about how it works or how it manages the files, which seems to be your problem.

It might be a problem with your permissions. Make sure that you launch the launcher with administrator privileges.

Otherwise, I suggest posting on TeamExtreme's [forums](http://forums.teamextrememc.com) in order for your problem to be fixed by those who have more experience with said cracked launcher.

But in all due respect, don't used cracked launchers. Support Mojang for their hard work.

Comment: Are you sure TeamExtreme is a cracked launcher? Also, the OP mentions that the problem still happens when they use the official launcher. There is a difference between a cracked launcher and a custom launcher (such as for example the FTB launcher), a custom launcher still requires you to own a minecraft caccount to play, and cracked launcher does not.

Answer (score -1):

That one because your graphic driver is outdated...
You need to updated you graphic driver

Graphic driver something like:
Intel